# python file operation slowing down on massive text files

Tags: python, list, text-processing

This python code is slowing down the longer it runs.

Can anyone please tell me why?

I hope it is not reindexing for every line I query and counting from start again, I thought it would be some kind of file-stream ?!

From 10k to 20k it takes 2 sec. from 300k to 310k it takes like 5 min. and getting worse.
The code is only running in the ELSE part up to that point and 'listoflines' is constant at that point (850000 lines in list) and of type 'list[ ]' as well as 'offset' is just a constant 'int' at that point.

The source file has millions of lines up to over 20 million lines.

'dummyline not in listoflines' should take the same time every time.

```
with open(filename, "rt") as source:
    for dummyline in source:
        if (len(dummyline) > 1) and (dummyline not in listoflines):
            # RUN compute
            # this part is not reached where I have the problem
        else:
            if dummyalreadycheckedcounter % 10000 == 0:
            print ("%d/%d: %s already checked or not valid " % (dummyalreadycheckedcounter, offset, dummyline) )
            dummyalreadycheckedcounter = dummyalreadycheckedcounter +1
```

Comment: I'm guessing that something may be growing in memory, and that the details are hidden in the bits that you have edited out. Even what you have shown is not indented correctly, which suggests that you have edited out lines inside your "else" block also.

Comment: thx, though I don't see anything wrong with the indentation up there but still it was just a copy paste from working code.. and there it is exactly doing what it should and nothing else..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually *in* operation for list is not the same every time in fact it is O(n) so it gets slower and slower as you add

you want to use set
See here https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity

You didn't ask for this but I'd suggest turning this into a processing pipe line, so your compute part would not be mixed with the dedup logic

```
def dedupped_stream(filename):
    seen = set()
    with open(filename, "rt") as source:
        for each_line in source:
            if len(line)>1 and each_line not in seen:
                seen.add(each_line)
                yield each_line
```

then you can do just

```
for line in dedupped_stream(...):
    ...
```

you would not need to worry about deduplication here at all

Answer (score 1):

Same opinion with @Sedy Vlk.
Use hash(that is dictionary in python) instead.

```py
clines_count = {l: 0 for l in clines}
for line in nlines:
    if len(line) > 1 and line in clines_count:
        pass
    else:
        if counter % 10000 == 0:
            print ("%d: %s already checked or not valid " % (counter, line) )
        counter += 1
```

Comment: You do not need a dictionary here at all just a set and `.add(line_you_saw)`